# accessing the standard layout attrributes in a custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, attributes

I want to pull out the width spec and height spec from the standard attributes passed to my custom view's constructor so I can tweak them and pass back as new layoutparams when I want to display the views rotated in an activity lock into portrait orientation.

I can't find out names the static int values in the intarray I need to pass to get at these raw values.  Where are they?

```
public static final int[] stdatts = {valForandroid:layout_width,...height,...gravity};
TypedArray natts = getContext().getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, stdatts);
int widset = natts.getInteger(valForandroid:layout_width, 0);
int hitset = ....;
int gravset = .....;
if (orientIsV) 
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams reset = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (widset, hitset, gravset);
else 
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams reset = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (hitset, widset, gravset);
```

I can find the values of these easily enough by looking at the attribute array I actually get passed, but this is obviously a very dirty and unreliable fix

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer I expected - I gave up trying to handle this in quite that way - the data format was very difficult to make sense of.  Here's part of the code for an extended relativelayout class that rotates, keeping everything inside it unchanged, it also keeps left / right alignment correct and correctly handles touch events.  It will allow a nested Seekbar to be in any direction for example, avoiding the need for a special case seekbar.

```
public void setOrientation() {
  if (rSource == RotateSetBy.globalStatic) {
    currRotate = PootleViewExtras.deviceOrient;
  }
  boolean isVert = currRotate == Orientations.up || currRotate == Orientations.down;
  if (lockSize > 0 && widthAtt < 0 && heightAtt < 0) {
    int lws = 0;
    int lhs = 0;
    if (isVert) {
      lws = widthAtt;
      lhs = heightAtt;
    } else {
      lhs = widthAtt;
      lws = heightAtt;
    }
    int setgrav = gravityAtt & 0x11; // messy but seems to do the right things
    if   (currRotate == Orientations.down ) {
      if ((gravityAtt & 0x2) != 0) setgrav |= 0x4;
      if ((gravityAtt & 0x4) != 0) setgrav |= 0x2;
      if ((gravityAtt & 0x20) != 0) setgrav |= 0x40;
      if ((gravityAtt & 0x40) != 0) setgrav |= 0x20;
    } else {
      setgrav = gravityAtt;
    }  

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams reset = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (lws, lhs, setgrav);
    this.setLayoutParams(reset);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

  boolean isVert = currRotate == Orientations.up || currRotate == Orientations.down;
  if (isVert)  {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    lastWidth = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    lastHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();
  } else {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    lastHeight = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    lastWidth = this.getMeasuredHeight();
  }
  setMeasuredDimension(lastWidth,lastHeight);
  switch (currRotate) {
    case up:
      mForward.reset();
      mForward.postRotate(0);
      mForward.invert(mReverse); 
      break;
    case right:
      mForward.reset();
      mForward.postRotate(90,lastWidth/2,lastWidth/2);
      mForward.invert(mReverse); 
      break;
    case down:
      mForward.reset();
      mForward.postRotate(180,lastWidth/2,lastHeight/2);
      mForward.invert(mReverse); 
      break;
    case left:
      mForward.reset();
      mForward.postRotate(-90,lastHeight/2,lastHeight/2);
      mForward.invert(mReverse);
      break;
  }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  if (currRotate == Orientations.up) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
  } else {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.concat(mForward);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
  }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//    if (currRotate == Orientations.up){
//      return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
//    } else {
  final float[] temp = mTemp;
  temp[0] = event.getX();
  temp[1] = event.getY();

  mReverse.mapPoints(temp);
  event.setLocation(temp[0], temp[1]);
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
//    }
```

Comment: This isn't fully working - in limited cases it works OK. It seems that various code does not properly use canvases to compute locations, so it looks like another approach is needed....